# Callback в python ctype

Tags: python, ctypes

Имеется dll-библиотека с экспортируемыми функциями SetCallback и FreeMemory. Функция SetCallback устанавливает функцию обратного вывода, а функция FreeMemory очищает память, которую выделяет библиотека. Также имеется код:

```
lib = WinDLL('txmlconnector')
WINCALLBACK = WINFUNCTYPE(c_bool, c_char_p)
def test(data):
    print(data.decode('utf8'))
    #FreeMemory(data)
    return True
callback = WINCALLBACK(test)
SetCallback = lib.SetCallback
SetCallback(callback)
```

Т.е. я передаю указатель на test в библиотеку dll.
Собственно код работает, функция test вызывается, но переменная data в ней имеет тип bytes, а я ожидаю указатель, т.к. мне нужно освободить выделенную под переменную data память (для этого импользуется функция FreeMemory из библиотеки dll). Как это исправить? Переменная data каким-то образом должна иметь тип c_char_p (либо что-то вроде того).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c_char_p` тип используется для `char*`, когда строки завершаются `'\0'` (нулевой байт), то есть для обычных С-строк. `ctypes` автоматически транслирует `c_char_p` в `bytes` (`_as_parameter_`) и обратно (`from_param()`).

Можно попробовать `POINTER(c_char)` тип использовать для `data` вместо `c_char_p`, чтобы выключить автоматическое преобразование и руками конвертировать внутри `test()` функции `s = cast(data, c_char_p).value`. В конце можно `FreeMemory(data)`, если библиотека выделяет память специально для `callback`.

Comment: Да. Решено с использованием более общего типа c_void_p и последующего преобразования cast. Подробности здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445568/python-ctypes-how-to-free-memory-getting-invalid-pointer-error

Comment: @morin: `POINTER(c_char)` работает как есть. В данном случае это не важно (для преобразования `char*` в `void*` и обратно), но в общем случае не следует, не думая, типы указателей преобразовывать, например, это может поменять выравнивание указателей (что может вызвать undefined behavior).